# php float precision, not accurate enough

Tags: php, precision

I've got a php script that does a really big calculation. The calculation works, but isn't precise enough. I need a way to actually use a precise number, so for example:

Currently:

```
.1 + .1 + .1 == .3
false
```

I need the real ans, so if I take 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1, than it needs to autput 0.3

My formula/calculation contains numbers like

```
1.1205673217773E-15
```

So eventually something like this should work:

```
(18 / 1025893) / 8900563 = 0.0000000000197
```

Or even better

```
1.971301080925020253843E-12
```

I need a precision of 1E-20 or better. I prefer to keep everything in php, else I'll need to write something in C++ and then call it from php or something.

**Can I use something that's more precise than float?**

**Can I adjust the precision of float points in php?**

**Is there a easy work-around?**

Comment: You can check out [bcmath](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.bc.php) for extra precision.

Comment: You could also write a PHP extension if you want to use C++

Comment: Do you really think that C++ will be more precise? It also use IEEE754 for floats

Comment: Did you actually read the docs on how to compare floats in PHP, not using `==`, but a precision delta (or epsilon) instead, [demo](https://3v4l.org/P0Knb)